# Scipy kd-tree implementation throwing "negative dimensions"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kdtree

I get the following error seemingly every time I try to do anything involving a kd-tree. Strangely, just days ago this very code was working fine, and it is still working fine on my colleague's machine (we are using the same repo).

It seems to happen no matter what I pass in.

Can anyone offer any insights?

```
  File "filename.py", line 69, in methodname
    get_index = self.kd_tree.query(array_to_query)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.12.0.dev_ddd617d_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 425, in query
    for c in np.ndindex(retshape):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_9597b1f_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py", line 536, in __init__
    x = as_strided(_nx.zeros(1), shape=shape, strides=_nx.zeros_like(shape))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_9597b1f_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 28, in as_strided
    return np.asarray(DummyArray(interface, base=x))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_9597b1f_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 320, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Comment: Do you know what the array is that's being passed to the last return statement?

Comment: There have been changes to `np.ndindex` and it appears it did support negative dimensions previously. However while it failing is nothing to be surprised about, I find it odd that it fails with a negative dimension error. Whats the shape of `array_to_query`? (its a known issue that `np.ndindex` needs some changing)

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but a sudo pip uninstall of numpy and scipy and a forced reinstall of both seems to have done the trick!

Comment: How can an array have negative dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found out the answer but a forced reinstall of numpy and scipy fixed the issue.